# Python keyboard listening on Windows and OSX

Tags: python, windows, macos, automation

I want to make a python script, compiled into an application, that runs in the background and listens for a given key combination. When those keys are struck, all kinds of fun stuff like log generating, screenshot taking, and website opening should happen. I've got those last three things covered.

The part I don't grasp right now is the "runs in the background and listens for a given key combination" bit.

My research included these previous threads:

[Python for Autohotkey style key-combination sniffing, automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294285/python-for-autohotkey-style-key-combination-sniffing-automation)

[Python cross-platform listening for keypresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044073/python-cross-platform-listening-for-keypresses)

So it's clear that I'll need to make slightly different versions of this application for the platforms I'm targeting (Windows and OSX). And neither thread suggests I'll have problems doing this on Windows.

For OSX, are there any equivalent libraries that listen for keyboard input? If not, would you more seasoned of scripters help me work through/kludge something that achieves the same thing?

EDIT: Background on why I want to do this sort of thing:

I commonly interact with a Flash program as part of my day-to-day, and I'm on a team responsible for bug capture, triage, fixing, and sending to QA. This Flash program will spit out logs when certain key combinations are entered, and the ticket information is generated through JIRA. With the information that the Flash file can export, information contained on the application's webpage source, and information contained in the URL, I can grab most of what I need to build a ticket without needing to track it all down and type it separately.

I have a working model of these functions in AutoHotKey, but that interpreter is limited at best. I'm trying to convert these functions to a more sane language, and hopefully accomplish multi-platform support at the same time. That way my team can benefit, too!

Comment: Could you add some context to your question so that it doesn't sound like you're a script kiddie trying to assemble a keylogger/windowspy that steals people's passwords and personal information and/or pulls their computer into a botnet?

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the main post with some background so less hasty assumptions get made.