# Calling AutoIt Functions in Python

Tags: python, autoit

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python/155587#155587) mentioned there is an AutoIt3 COM version, and with it I can call AutoIt functions in Python.

I couldn't find the COM version at the AutoIt website. Is it hidden somewhere? How can I get it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## How to use AutoItX COM/DLL in python

There are two methods for using AutoIt in Python:

1. [pyautoit module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt)
2. [python for windows extentions (pywin32)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

The pyautoit module will make use of the DLL while with pywin32 we can use the COM.  As far as I know, there is no functional difference between the two.

### Prerequisites

1. An installation of [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. An installation of [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/).
3. An installation of either [pyautoit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt) or [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

Not all AutoIt functions are available through the COM/DLL interface.  To see which functions are, see the help file on AutoItX.

### Pyautoit

Install via pip or your preferred method:

```
pip install -U pyautoit
```

If you get an error: `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` when installing pyautoit, use the 32 bit version of python.  I haven't been able to get pyautoit to install using the 64 bit version of python. Of course, your mileage may vary.

Import and use:

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.win_close("[CLASS:Notepad]")
autoit.control_click("[Class:#32770]", "Button2")
```

The autoit commands all use lower_case_with_underscores rather than AutoItX's preferred CamelCase.  Thus ControlSend becomes control_send, WinClose becomes win_close, etc.

### Pywin32

Once pywin32 is installed, call AutoItX functions by:

```
import win32com.client
autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")

autoit.Run("NotePad.exe")
autoit.ControlClick(WINDOW, "", "[CLASSNN:TTreeView1]", "left", 1, 53, 41)
```

If you have trouble with this version, install everything as 32 bit and try again.

Comment: Do you know where to find PyAutoIt documentation or tutorial?

Comment: @Mawg I'm not sure if this s still any help but I found this AutoItX COM/DLL documentation: https://documentation.help/AutoItX/

Answer (score 10):

`AutoItX.dll` and `AutoItX3_x64.dll` are included in the default installation, in a directory called "AutoItX". Check out the help file `AutoItX.chm` in that directory for more info.

Comment: in windows 7 run cmd as administrator go to AutoItX.dll and execute regsvr32.exe AutoItX3.dll

Comment: also run regsvr32.exe AutoItX3_x64.dll .Might be helpful.