# How do I add autoit to Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, autoit

I am new to python and trying to write scripts in Spyder that use autoit but keep getting an error when I import autoit :

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoit'*

Comment: did you install `autoit` ? Is this python's module ? If not then you can't import it.

Comment: make sure `autoit` is available in your `PYTHONPATH`. What is the output of `pip list | grep -i autoit`, i am assuming you are working in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `pip install -U pyautoit` and then add `import autoit`

You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301561/calling-autoit-functions-in-python) question. Hope it will help you