# Electron / Node.js find third party app window position - Overlay for another app

Tags: node.js, electron

Is it possible with electron/node to find another third party app window size and position?

I want to write an overlay for a game, and position my electron window above it at a certain position according to the game window.

Comment: Maybe try to integrate python script like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python) or C/C++ addon at least? Because seems like NodeJS doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: For which operating systems? I know in Windows, for example, you can tap into the Win32 API using node-ffi to get this type of information, but I am not sure how this could be done in OSX or Linux.

Comment: Ofcourse for Windows AND macOS :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [electron-overlay-window package](https://github.com/SnosMe/electron-overlay-window).

Supports:

- Windows (7 - 10)
- Linux (X11)

It tracks target windows by its title and keeps your app window right over it. It also re-attaches itself if you restart the target app/game. The only downside - it's not very documented. But basic demo is very simple if you have any experience with electron.

Pay attention - it will only work for windowed or windowed borderless modes. The electron window can not be placed over the fullscreen game.

```
// ...
import { overlayWindow as OW } from 'electron-overlay-window'

// ...
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  ...OW.WINDOW_OPTS,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  resizable: false,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
  },
})

// ... when ready
OW.attachTo(window, 'Untitled - Notepad')

// listen for lifecycle events
OW.on('attach', ev => { console.log('WO: attach', ev) })
OW.on('detach', ev => { console.log('WO: detach', ev) })
OW.on('blur', ev => { console.log('WO: blur', ev)})
OW.on('focus', ev => { console.log('WO: focus', ev)})
OW.on('fullscreen', ev => console.log('WO: fullscreen', ev))
OW.on('moveresize', ev => console.log('WO: fullscreen', ev))
```

You can look up more examples here:

- [Ender-O for Elite Dangerous](https://github.com/vovchisko/ender-o) written in JS ([demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xoxKqmILuI))
- [Awaken PoE Trade for Path of Exile](https://github.com/SnosMe/awakened-poe-trade) written in TS
- [Simple demo from author](https://github.com/SnosMe/electron-overlay-window/tree/master/src/demo) written in TS (I recommend starting with this example)