# Get resolution of specific screen running using python

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to get the resolution of the specific window. Is there any option that it is possible?
for example, I would to get 800 X 600, the resolution of the gta
link to the picture to understand what I meant https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Jm1.jpg

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get other running processes window sizes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [`pygetwindow`](https://pypi.org/project/PyGetWindow/):

```
>>> import pygetwindow as gw

>>> window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Grand Theft Auto V')[0]

>>> window.height
600
>>> window.width
800
```